# Show modal above iframe when iframe is in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fullscreen

I have an HTML page with an Iframe inside. I need to show the iframe in Fullscreen mode, and when I'm in such mode I need to show some Modal dialogs which are placed within the "base" HTML page.

As a solution I tried to dinamically append the dialog to the iframe's body. The modal shows, but the actions aren't executed (button clicks, etc.). I'd like to avoid, if possible, to recreated the event listeners each time I've to show a modal dialog.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: try increasing z-index of your modal dialogue.

Comment: @Yunus no, this is not a z-index problem, they are on different documents.